# Can I Order Results Using Two Columns from Different Tables?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, join

I have a Rails application featuring a city in the US. I'm working on a database process that will feature businesses that pay to be on the website. The goal is to feature businesses within an hour's drive of the city's location in order to make visitors aware of what is available. My goal is to group the businesses by city where the businesses in the city are listed first then the businesses from the next closest city are displayed. I want the cities to be listed by distance and the businesses within the city group to be listed by the business name.

I have two tables that I want to join in order to accomplish this.

```
city (has_many :businesses) - name, distance

business (belongs_to :city) - name, city_id, other columns
```

I know I can do something like the statement below that should only show data where business rows exist for a city row.

```
@businesses = City.order(“distance ASC").joins('JOIN businesses ON businesses.city_id = cities.id')
```

I would like to add order by businesses.name. I've seen an example `ORDER BY a.Date, p.title` which referencing columns from two databases.

```
ORDER BY a.Date, p.title
```

Can I add code to my existing statement to order businesses by name or will I have to embed SQL code to do this? I have seen examples with other databases doing this but either the answer is not Rails specific or not using PostgreSQL.

Comment: ORDER BY with multiple sort columns is not Postgres specific. `City.order(“distance ASC, businesses.name").joins(:businesses)` should work. You don't seem to have tried whether it works?! Please try it before asking here.

Comment: @Raffael I have submitted 89 questions in this forum the past few years. I do what I can to try things and do my research as the guidelines state. If I had come up with something to try I would have before posting my question. This is one time I was not able to consider something to try after hours of online research. BTW your solution did not find any records. I will keep working with my code and hopefully find a solution.

Comment: I forgot to include that the relationships are correct in my models and the data exists in my tables. When I display a Business row the correct City name appears on the screen.

Comment: Sorry to be so unforgiving. Guess I was tired. Glad you found a solution that works for you! Let me give you two pointers that might be helpful in the future: the `to_sql` and `merge` methods on relations.

Comment: @Raffael that can happen when you are tired or hungry. Apology accepted. I'm saving the link of this question because of things you posted I was not aware of. The .joins clause you suggested (which I have never used) can be useful in other instances where I only need access to a few columns using .pluck. Thanks for the other suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

After lots more research I was finally able to get this working the way I wanted to.

Using `.joins(:businesses)` did not yield anything because it only included the columns for City aka BusinessCity and no columns for Business. I found that you have to use `.pluck` or `.select` to get access to the columns from the table you are joining. This is something I did not want to do because I foresee more columns being added in the future.

I ended up making Business the main table instead of BusinessCity as my starting point since I was listing data from Business on my view as stated in my initial question. When I did this I could not use the `.joins(:business_cities)` clause because it said the relation did not exist. I decided to go back to what I had originally started with using Business as the main table.

I came up with the following statement that provides all the columns from both tables ordered by distance on the BusinessCity table and name on the Business table. I was successful in added `.where` clauses as needed to accommodate the search functionality on my view.

```
@businesses = Business.joins("JOIN business_cities ON business_cities.id = businesses.business_city_id").order("business_cities.distance, businesses.name")
```